# Text transform capitalize effects a url name

Tags: css

I have a heading with a url in it that is capitalizing the .com portion (ie Urlname.Com). This is undesirable. Is there a way to change this without removing the `text-transform: capitalize`  rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, wrap the domain in a `span`, and use `text-transform:none` for the span element

Comment: Without a pure CSS method this does seem like the most semantic way to go about it